# Upgrading Operating System only. OS 2016 - 2019

Tags: sql-server-2017, upgrade, windows-server, windows-server-2019

Currently we have a number of Servers that are using Windows 2016 with SQL Server 2017. The support team want to do an in-place upgrade of the OS to 2019 due to 2016 Mainstream support ending in Jan 2022. I don't want to upgrade the SQL Server versions, so I am wondering if it is Ok to just upgrade the OS? I will obviously be taking backups and the like but just wanted to know if there were any gotchas I should be aware of before agreeing with the OS upgrade?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read up on Database Compatibility at https://aka.ms/dbcompat

What this will tell you is that validation is not done at the SQL Server major version level but at the database level.  This should ease your concerns about upgrading from SQL Server 2017 to 2019.

However, if you are staying on the same version for cost purposes (e.g. you don't have software assurance to get free upgrades) then running SQL Server 2017 on Windows 2019 is fully supported and does not change the features or functionality of SQL Server.  See the [support matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259#operating-system-support) for confirmation of that